# Combining vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

what are 3 ways to combine distinct vector spaces?

I can think of the Cartesian product and have proved it is a vector space

I can't think of any others.

Comment: There are many ways to combine vectors spaces. Perhaps you meant combine them in such a way that the result is also a vector space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $F$ and $G$ are vector subspaces of a vector space $E$ you can also consider $F\cap G$, or $E/F$. If you have a scalar product defined in your space you could also consider $F_\perp$. The dual space $E^*$.

Comment: the vector spaces are distinct, does that just mean they're not the same?

Comment: I don't have any context of your exercise, but I would say so. Anyway, if you are not allowed to use different subspaces of the same space you could consider the following: $E$ and $F$ distinct vector spaces. $L(E,F)$ is the space of linear maps $f:E\rightarrow F$. And, as I said before, the dual space.

Answer (score 3):

I would say

1. Tensorial Product
2. Direct Sum
3. Intersection